# Trim every string in object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string

I have an XML parser and i want to trim whitespace and new lines before it goes to the app delegate. I know it only works with string, but how to do it for the elements inside the object. **More important is it smart to do this or is it better to do a separate trimming**

```
newString =[menu.enable stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: menu.enable is the string that i'm trimming. Making menu the object in whom the string is in. Don't mind my code, it's just an example. How to make this for the whole object, every string to be trimmed before i take them out

Comment: So let me understand this better. You have a instance of a custom object `menu` which has properties some of which are strings. These strings need to be trimmed. Have I got this right?

Comment: there is an object that has string and url instances and it is getting it's values while parsing an XML file. So when i try to make a condition, lets say  `if ([something isEqualToString:@"true"])`  true is nowhere to be found because it has new lines in front of it in the XML doc and it was parsed with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had my run ins with this issue myself, and it's not trivial. SriPriya's solution works but only if there are no newlines in the element content. This:

```
<foo>
    hello
    hi
</foo>
```

would (IIRC) come out as

```
@"hello\n    hi"
```

when trimmed that way.

The solution I came up with to solve this (and there may be more elegant solutions out there - I'm all ears) is the following:

Presuming you're using NSXMLParser with a delegate class that handles the actual parsing (as in SriPriya's example above), where the `-parser:foundCharacters:` method is located, you would do:

```
- (NSString *)removeNewlinesAndTabulation:(NSString *)fromString appending:(BOOL)appending
{
    NSArray *a = [fromString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    NSMutableString *res = [NSMutableString stringWithString:appending ? @" " : @""];
    for (NSString *s in a) {
        s = [s stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        if (s.length > 0 
            && res.length > (appending ? 1 : 0)) [res appendString:@" "];
        [res appendString:s];
    }
    return res;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
{   
    if (! currentElementValue) {
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[self removeNewlinesAndTabulation:string appending:NO]];
    } else {
        [currentElementValue appendString:[self removeNewlinesAndTabulation:string appending:currentElementValue.length > 0]];
    }
}
```

I know it looks like a lot of code for something this simple, but it will correctly turn

```
<foo>
  hi there all
  i am typing some
     stuff
</foo>
```

into

```
@"hi there all i am typing some stuff"
```

which sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: I will try this solution of yours. Thank you for the sample code. One more thing, are you sure  NSArray *a = [fromString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
works with new lines, cause i have tried to search for "/n" character and there are none but the NSLog shows the data in new line.

Comment: Maybe because you wrote "/n" instead of "\n" as in your comment? ;) If not, then I have no idea, but the above does indeed work. I use it with multiple XML files containing newlines.

Answer (score 3):

In

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{


NSString *trimmedValue=[currentElementValue stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];


        //NSLog(@"current value:%@",currentElementValue);
        [aFile setValue:trimmedValue forKey:elementName];

}
```

it will trim every element before saving it to an object. Here, aFile is object